# UICollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths failure

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)deleteCell 
{
        [self.collectionViewMenu performBatchUpdates:^{

           [self.itemsArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
           NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
           [self.collectionViewMenu deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {  }];
}
```

Please help to solve this problem, what am I doing wrong? I got this error after trying to delete an item in my collectionView.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: <_UICollectionViewItemKey: 0x8d705e0> Type = SV Kind = UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader IndexPath = <NSIndexPath: 0x8d6f4b0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})'
```

Comment: did u reload collection view after deletion?

Comment: no in - (void)deleteCell method is all what I do...

Answer (score 3):

I solve the problem with remove the header and footer size delegates. the problem was in the fact that I do not return a header or footer.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Answer (score 0):

`setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil` means that the cell you are trying to delete is possibly already been deleted. 
You should try to debug it and see when you call the delete what views at what index paths are actually in your collection view.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to implement:

`- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

in your dataSource. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just try to call `collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` before `performBatchUpdates`. Then make sure the layout implementation are correctly and make sure that you are not returning negative height for cell. For more detail you can visit below GitHub link.
https://github.com/ra1028/DifferenceKit/issues/13

It helped me to fix the error.